# Best Way to Load a File, Manipulate the Data, and Write a New File

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have an issue where I need to load a fixed-length file.  Process some of the fields, generate a few others, and finally output a new file.  The difficult part is that the file is of part numbers and some of the products are superceded by other products (which can also be superceded).  What I need to do is follow the superceded trail to get information I need to replace some of the fields in the row I am looking at.  So how can I best handle about 200000 lines from a file and the need to move up and down within the given products?  I thought about using a collection to hold the data or a dataset, but I just don't think this is the right way.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
Before


Part Number      List Price          Description                   Superceding Part Number        
 0913982                                                                        3852943        
 3852943            0006710            CARRIER,BEARING          

After


Part Number      List Price          Description                   Superceding Part Number      
 0913982            0006710            CARRIER,BEARING      3852943      
 3852943            0006710            CARRIER,BEARING
```

As usual any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Wade

Comment: Why do you think creating a collection (and using linq to find the superceding parts) is not a viable solution?

Comment: @rontornambe I guess I can't be sure what will work on so many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create structure of given fields.
Read file and put structures in collection. You may use part number as key for hashtable to provide fastest searching.

Scan collection and fix the data.

200 000 objects from given lines will fit easily in memory.

For example.
If your structure size is 50 bytes then you will need only 10Mb of memory. It is nothing for modern PC.